# Why doesn't a Hang-glider Stop Moving Forward, Stall and Fall?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, aircraft

Why doesn't a hang-glider stop moving forward (because of air resistance), stall and fall?

Comment: [Hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal).

Comment: just like the gliding birds. they do not stall .

Comment: Why doesn't a snow boarder stop moving because of friction between the board and the snow? (Hint: they eventually _do_ stop when they reach the bottom of the hill.)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly hang-gliders (or any type of glider) are designed to have a very low stall speed. Secondly, a glider converts the potential energy of its height into kinetic energy to maintain sufficient speed relative to the air to prevent stalling. Thirdly, a glider converts thermal energy into potential energy by finding thermals which allow it to regain the height that it has lost.

(Imagine a snowboarder who, at the bottom of a valley, can often grab onto a convenient ski lift to take them up to the top of the next hill).